# Trying to sort a list of objects however: java: int cannot be dereferenced

Tags: java

So I have an object TeamStats.

I would like to be able to sort a teamStats list by `gamesWon` however, when I try to implement the compareTo method as shown below, I am getting the error message: `java: int cannot be dereferenced`.

I cannot figure out why that is, as I am following [this ArrayList sorting tutorial](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/collections/arraylist/arraylist-sort-objects-by-field/)  and they do not seem to have the same problem.

Why am I getting this error and how do I avoid it?

```
package sample;

import java.util.Comparator;

public class TeamStats implements Comparator<TeamStats>  {

    int teamID;
    int gamesPlayed;
    int gamesWon;
    int setsWon;

    public TeamStats(int teamID, int gamesPlayed, int gamesWon, int setsWon) {
        this.teamID = teamID;
        this.gamesPlayed = gamesPlayed;
        this.gamesWon = gamesWon;
        this.setsWon = setsWon;
    }

    public int getTeamID() {
        return teamID;
    }

    public void setTeamID(int teamID) {
        this.teamID = teamID;
    }

    public int getGamesPlayed() {
        return gamesPlayed;
    }

    public void setGamesPlayed(int gamesPlayed) {
        this.gamesPlayed = gamesPlayed;
    }

    public int getGamesWon() {
        return gamesWon;
    }

    public void setGamesWon(int gamesWon) {
        this.gamesWon = gamesWon;
    }

    public int getSetsWon() {
        return setsWon;
    }

    public void setSetsWon(int setsWon) {
        this.setsWon = setsWon;
    }


    @Override
    public int compare(TeamStats o1, TeamStats o2) {
        return o2.getGamesWon().compareTo(o1.getGamesWon());
    }
}
```

Comment: Better to have it implement `Comparable<TeamStats>` and override the `compareTo` method. Better to return `Integer.compare(....)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`int`s in java are native types, not objects. As such they don't have methods (in your example `compareTo`)

The call `o2.getGamesWon()` returns a native `int` not an `Integer` (the wrapper type).

Change the code to the following and it should work

```
    @Override
    public int compare(TeamStats o1, TeamStats o2) {
        // Thanks to Hovercraft Full Of Eels!
        return Integer.compare(o1.getGamesWon(), o2.getGamesWon()); 
    }
```

Comment: As always - of course there is a guy who beats me to the answer by 5 sec. Good job, man! :D

Comment: The canonical solution is not to use subtraction but rather to use `Integer.compare(...)` which handles edge cases better

Answer (score 4):

Of course the answer of @Augusto is completely correct.

Here is just another possibility to create a `Comparator<TeamStats>` without implementing the `Comparator` interface directly:

```
Comparator<TeamStats> comparator = Comparator.comparing(TeamStats::getGamesWon);
```